# Customizing popup using C++ Qt SDK

Tags: c++, qt, sdk

I have a KML layer on my map. I want to have a customized popup that will appear on click of placemark on my KML layer. I want to have customized fields in my popup.

I am using C++ qt SDK and tried to create the popup (as shown in the below code), but it is not working properly, It still gives me a default popup with the placemark city name (Attaching result below).

code:

```
  for (GeoElement* geoElement : elements)
  {
    QJsonObject root;
    root["Name"] = "Sample1";
    root["Age"] = "20";
    root["city"] = "Mumbai";
    QJsonDocument doc(root);
    QList<PopupElement*> elist;
    QString strJson(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
    PopupElement* ele = PopupElement::fromJson(strJson,this);
    elist.append(ele);
    PopupDefinition* popdef = new PopupDefinition(geoElement);
    popdef->setElements(elist);
    Popup* popup = new Popup(geoElement, popdef);
    // create a popup manager
    PopupManager* popupManager = new PopupManager{popup, this};
    // append popup manager to list
    m_popupManagers.append(popupManager);
    // notify QML that m_popupManagers has changed and to display the popup(s).
    emit popupManagersChanged();
  }
```

}
}

Output:

[image]

Comment: Added code lines, also attached output popup.